# Merging table columns and rows into single cell

Tags: html, html-table

I need to create a email signature and I am having a bit of a struggle. I have to use a table but I have to merge it like this.

Here is what I currently have:

```
_____|_______|________
_____|_______|________
_____|_______|________
```

---

```
<table width="550" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table
```

This is what I need (merge the left three columns with the top three columns):

```
         ____________________
        |__________|_________
________|__________|_________
```

Comment: What you need is 'rowspan' attribute http://www.angelfire.com/fl5/html-tutorial/tables/rowspan.htm

Comment: Now that I fully understand your question, what's the point of merging the top 3 columns... you just get one row which could be whatever you want above the table.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**

I now understand the trick to this question... You also want the top row to merge WITH the merged columns on the left? Not possible. But you might be able to fake something like it with some CSS, [rowspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) and [colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp).

**New fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/HpkpY/4/

Bear in mind that these are not truly merged - they only appear as though. And if the `border-collapse` property was not set to `collapse`, you'd probably get some weird results.

---

**Old answer:**

[rowspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) will help!

**JSFiddle Demonstration:**
http://jsfiddle.net/HpkpY/1/

```
<table width="550" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*Don't forget to remove the other cells you no longer need due to the merge!*

Comment: Doesn't answer the question asked: OP wanted the top row spanned, too.

Comment: Cool.  Please check my comment I've added on the original post and add what you think.